# unable to upgrade flutter on mac

Tags: flutter

I am unable to update flutter on osX.

When I run:

```
flutter doctor
```

I get the following error:

```
Because flutter_tools depends on xml >=3.5.0 which requires SDK version >=2.3.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
The current Dart SDK version is 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.
```

I have not idea how to solve this issue since I cannot issue any flutter commands.

I tried to cd into the flutter/bin directory and do :

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

But this did not solve my issues.

Any ideas ? I don't have sudo rights.

Comment: add your pubspec file

Comment: @MuratAslan which pubspec, the one in the flutter_tools folder ?

Comment: Probably need to update your Dart SDK version

Comment: can you run the command 'flutter doctor -v' and post the complete results

Comment: Is the issue resolved ?

Comment: @sivakumar yes. I ran: rew upgrade cocoapods and
pod setup, then it worked. But I am not 100 % that this was the fix since I launched many operations before.